# Computing differences between columns of tab delimited file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a tab delimited file of 4 columns and n number of rows.

I want to find the difference in values present in column 3 and 2 and want to store them in another file.

This is what I am doing

```
cat filename | awk '{print $3 - $2}'>difference
```

and it is not working. How can I improve the code?

---

*Solution:*

> I was missing the closing single quotation, and my eyes were so tuned to the screen that I couldn't figure it out in 35 lines code what was going wrong...and out of frustration I wrote the question on forum ... and [to complete] the comedy of errors, the syntax I wrote here [in the] question is correct (as it contains both single quotes).
>
> Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Yet another [UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html).

Comment: @larsmans: thank you for being so critical ... I am a newbie in shell who is trying to learn

Comment: In what way is it 'not working'?  Have you tried diagnostic printing of the `$3` and `$2` values to see whether you're getting the right split on the line?  If the columns are numeric, the script you have should work.  Which platform are you on?  If it is being run on Windows in a DOS command terminal, could the problem be the use of single quotes vs double quotes?  Also, you might need a space before the '`>`' in some environments.  Unix shell will be OK without it...others might not be.

Comment: It is working now, I made a very small error and rectified it myself.

Comment: @Angelo - Can you edit your comment and let us know what the issue was?

Comment: I was missing the closing single quotation, and my eyes were so tuned to the screen that I couldn't figure it out in 35 lines code what was going wrong.....and out of frustration I wrote the question on forum .... and see the comedy of errors, that the syntax I wrote here on question is correct (as it contains both single quotes). Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does anyone test before they give their answers/ `awk` breaks on white space and not just spaces.

I just did this:

```
awk '{print $3 - $2}' temp.txt
```

And it works perfectly.

Here's my file:

```
1   2       7       4
11  12      13      14
1   12      3       4
1   2       3       4
1   2       3       4
```

And here's my results:

```
$ awk '{print $3 - $2}' temp.txt
5
1
-9
1
1
$
```

In fact, I used your command, and got the same results?

Can you explain what's not working for you? What data are you using, and what results are you getting?

Comment: Thank you, it is working I made a very small error which rectified. As soon as my code started working I did attach a comment beneath my question. thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Set the field separator if you have other whitespace in the lines.

```
BEGIN {
  FS="\t"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `-F` to force the delimiter as tab and enclose your

```
cat filename | awk -F"\t" '{print $3 - $2}' > difference
```

Comment: awk splits on white space be default

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

cat filename | awk -F '^T' '{print $3 - $4}' > difference

where `^T` is tab delimiter (get it by pressing Ctrl+V+T)

Comment: awk splits on white space by default